# SQL Server 2005 - Unspecified error in Visual Database Tools

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a Win7 Pro machine (64 bit), running SQL Server 2005 with SQL Server Management Studio Express 2005 (v 9.00.2047) and Visual Studio 2012. I have a C# application that uses the database (using windows authentication) and everything has worked perfectly for months until yesterday ...

My application was crashing out due to a database timeout. Management Studio Express would time out connecting with the error message in the title. I spent some time on Google yesterday and the most common suggestion was a software update - there were no updates on the machines in the past week.

I have extended the time for timeouts but it has made no difference. There is no limit on the number of connections to the database. I was able to provide a temporary fix by rebooting the machine and the database would connect again for a few hours, but now I can't connect at all.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Have you checked the disks on the machine? Any unusual noises? This kind of thing could easily be the early stages of a hardware failure. Anything in the logs (both system and SQL)? Checked http://dba.stackexchange.com? Because this might be more in the line of SQL Server admin than programming...

Comment: @Matt - I haven't. There have been no unusual noises from the disks (in fact no noise at all). When Management Studio Express does work, it is extraordinarily slow in reading tables.